# Center view on y axis when view controller is embedded in a navigation controller

Tags: ios, autolayout

Using auto layout in XCode 5, how can i center a view on the y axis when the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

I'm using storyboards and trying to use auto layout. I have a navigation controller and the root view controller to the nav controller is just a simple view controller with just a button in the view.[image]

Now, i can choose to add the constraint "Center vertically in container", but when i do that the button is centered in the entire app view, not the actual view below the navigation controller.

View hierarchy:
[image: This view controller is then embedded in a navigation controller]

Makes sense?

Comment: Chances are the "actual view below the navigation controller" is in fact the full height of the screen and extends behind the navigation bar. Uncheck 'under top bars' in the View Controller options to change  this...

Comment: The buttons superview is the view controllers view. button view -> view controller view -> navigation controller view

Comment: @MikePollard Brilliant! That did the trick:) XCode and all those checkboxes. Dont really understand why that is the default behaviour. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: I'd simplify those constraint too. You only need 'Center Y' and the two 'Horizontal space' ones. I think you can delete the others...

Comment: It's the default behaviour now because of iOS7's use of translucent bars.

Comment: @MikePollard's comment should be accepted answer

Comment: If you're using a non-translucent bar, there's also an 'Under Opaque Bars' option too, which is not selected by default.